# Is it possible to change Return-Path in Sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I just changed Return-Path in 2 of my servers which run Exim and Posfix. The third server runs Sendmail. I spent several hours trying to find information how to change it but can not find anything. So, I need to change Return-Path so that sent emails contain Return-Path: root@mydomain.com instead of root@my-servers-hostname.com.

I can not change the server's hostname itself because my data center wants additional 5 EUR/month for a custom PTR record.

Thanks.

Comment: 5 euros per month to set a PTR record? That's utterly absurd. Any reputable host will allow you to set these for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy from the bat book:

> There must be only one Return-Path: header in any mail message, and it
>   should be placed there by the site performing final delivery. This
>   header should be declared in the configuration file like this:
>
> H?P?Return-Path: $g
>
> The ?P? flag ensures that only delivery agents
>   that perform final delivery insert this header. Those delivery agents
>   are usually prog and local, which usually contain an F=P delivery
>   agent flag

So if you want to set it to something else at the bottom of your sendmail.mc add the following lines:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
H?P?Return-Path: blah-blah
```

Also note that if this header is already defined, then it cannot be replaced unless sendmail was compiled with `H_ACHECK` defined for `conf.c`.

Comment: sendmail.mc file didn't contain "Return-Path". So, I added your suggested lines, restarted sendmail. No effect. Sendmail still uses server's hostname as a return-path.

Comment: You need to produce a new `sendmail.cf` after you edit `sendmail.mc`.

Answer (score 1):

https://web.archive.org/web/20161120105550/http://www.sendmail.com:80/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading.html

As I understand you look for FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')
[only "header sender"/"From:" is modified by default, other features extend it]

P.S. If you want to keep "header sender"/"From:" unchanged AFAIR it possible with FEATURE(`genericstable').

Comment: You may ask sendmail related questions at news:comp.mail.sendmai

Answer (score 0):

Aaargh. Bloody dawn horrible m4.
I do not use it, never did.
I create my sendmail.cf by hand

You need to code a rule called like this to change the right side
of the mail addr to whatever you want
H?P?Return-Path: $>Rule

SRule
....

Code the rule on it own with a name outside H for headers inside sendmail.cf alone out of any other rule
Test it with

sendmail -bt -d21.12

> ?
> rules addr

NameOfRule root@mydomain.com

see if it comes as you like
root@my-servers-hostname.com

Be aware of DMARC with spf & dkim validation
The From: domain part be same in the Return-Path domain part
So my advice change both or leave alone.

And read the bat book.
No blogs, nothing else.

Poor Exim and Posfix they are a shame :-((, miles behind sendmail